# I have problem in sending mail in laravel with queue and scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, task-queue

I am using laravel and i need to send mail. I configured cron job and scheduler but i have a peculiar problem.

I can see that my tasks were entering the jobs table.but,when the `queue:work` execute by cron job and scheduler the Jobs table be empty and also failed-jobs empty, too and I have not received any email.

My cron job command :

```
usr/local/phpcron/Isphplaravel73 / LaravelApp-path/artisan schedule:run >>/dev/null 2>&1
```

app/console/kernel.php :

```
    Protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $this->command('queue:work')->withoutOverlapping() ;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What operating your server is using linix or windows

Comment: I am using linux server

Comment: what are you using the send the mail, and to what address ... it is possible if it is going to a webmail that it is in the spam folder or being denied completely

Comment: I am using my own host mail Server. I have question. In What case It denied completely?

Comment: @DieHard Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to Run Laravel schedule:run command each minute, following method will be use,

**1. Make a cronjob into Linux**

To edit or create crontab file, type the following command at the UNIX / Linux shell prompt:

`$ crontab -e`

then write Laravel Command in crontab

`* * * * * usr/local/phpcron/Isphplaravel73 / LaravelApp-path/artisan schedule:run >>/dev/null 2>&1`

**2. Make a cronjob into your cPanel shared hosting**
In this step, we have to define cPanel cronjob for running our laravel schedule in every minute. For that, login into cPanel and goto Cron Jobs option then create a new cronjob like below.
Select `Once Per Minute` option from **Common Settings** dropdown box.

In the command text box put the value according to this format.

Format: `/usr/local/bin/php /home/hosting_user_name/your_artisan_file_path schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

After putting the command in the command text box, click the **Add New Cron Job** button.

[image]

**if Still not Working Check job output on each job run**

```
Protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $this->command('queue:work')->withoutOverlapping()->sendOutputTo($filePath) ;
}
```

`sendOutputTo` laravel method for get output in file. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#task-output

Comment: But i am using shared host, so i have not access to SSH

Comment: I did exactly that, But no email has been sent yet

Comment: there was nothing on falied_jobs table but in log file Written : [2020-09-13 15:29:29][50] Failed : JobClassName

Comment: Ok please mention whole log detail in your question

Comment: [2020-09-13 17:49:47][53] Processing: App\Jobs\VerificationAdmin
[2020-09-13 17:49:47][53] Processed:  App\Jobs\VerificationAdmin
[2020-09-13 17:49:47][54] Processing: App\Mail\VerificationAdmin
[2020-09-13 17:50:17][54] Failed:     App\Mail\VerificationAdmin              @Artier

Comment: Is this not due to smtp server failure?in local and mailtrap i have not any problem

Comment: it is test of my smtp server (https://www.wormly.com/test-smtp-server/host/cp16.uploadguy.com/port/465/sendmail/1/id/C4f7OeGR)

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/mailsend-not-working-in-in-sever-cron-job. Use this link

Answer (score 0):

It's not laravel or php issue, it's the server's fault. I have had this issue before, either buy premium email or use gmail smtp. Server's default emails does not work with cron as per my experience.